# How to access a component's instance in an another instance of the same component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to learn Vue 3 by creating a month planner app.

The entire has the following structure:

[image: project structure]

The calendar body component is as follows:

```
<template>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item" v-for="(month, index) in months" :key="month">
            {{ month }} 
            <hr> 
            <TaskContainer  @toggle-side-panel='handleTogglePanel'
                            @close-side-panel='handleClosePanel'
                            @add-to-all-tasks='handleAddToAllTasks'
                            @del-from-all-tasks='handleDelFromAllTasks'
                            :allTasks=allTasks 
                            :activeMonth=(index+1) />
        </div>

        <div v-show="showPanel">
            <CalendarSidePanel :task='task'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import TaskContainer from '../Task/TaskContainer.vue'
    import CalendarSidePanel from './CalendarSidePanel.vue'
    import { ref, reactive, toRefs } from '@vue/runtime-core'

    export default {
        name: 'CalendarBody',

        components: {
            TaskContainer,
            CalendarSidePanel
        },

        setup(props) {
            console.log('CalendarBody task ', props.task);
            const allTasks = ref([]);
            const showPanel = ref(false);
            const lastTask = ref(null);
            const task = ref(null);

            const state = reactive({
                months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
            });

            function handleTogglePanel(tsk) {
                console.group('CalendarBody_handleTogglePanel');
                console.log('tsk ', tsk);

                if(tsk != null) {
                    task.value = tsk;
                    console.log('showPanel ', showPanel.value);
                    console.log('task ', task.value);
                    console.log('lastTask.value ', lastTask.value);

                    if(lastTask.value == null || lastTask.value != task.value.tName) {
                        console.log('lastTask is null or different ', lastTask);
                        showPanel.value = true;
                        lastTask.value = task.value.tName;
                        console.log('lastTask is assigned or changed', lastTask);
                    } else if(lastTask.value == task.value.tName) {
                        console.log('lastTask is the same ', lastTask);
                        showPanel.value = false;
                        lastTask.value = null;
                    }
                }
                console.groupEnd('CalendarBody_handleTogglePanel');
            }
            
            function handleAddToAllTasks(singleTask) {
                console.group('CalendarBody_handleAddToAllTasks');
                allTasks.value.push(singleTask);
                console.groupEnd('CalendarBody_handleAddToAllTasks');
            }

            function handleDelFromAllTasks(taskName) {
                console.group('CalendarBody_handleDelFromAllTasks');
                console.log('BEFORE: deleting from allTasks ', allTasks.value);
                allTasks.value = allTasks.value.filter(t => t.tName != taskName);
                console.log('AFTER: deleting from allTasks ', allTasks.value);                
                console.groupEnd('CalendarBody_handleDelFromAllTasks');
            }

            function handleClosePanel(taskName) {
                console.group('CalendarBody_handleClosePanel');
                if(showPanel.value && taskName == lastTask.value) {
                    showPanel.value = false;
                    lastTask.value = null;
                }
                console.groupEnd('CalendarBody_handleClosePanel');
            }
        
            return {
                ...toRefs(state),
                allTasks,
                task,
                showPanel,
                handleClosePanel,
                handleTogglePanel,
                handleAddToAllTasks,
                handleDelFromAllTasks
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
        background-color: #2196F3;
        padding: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .grid-item {
        background-color: #2196F3;
        margin: 2px;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
</style>
```

Task container:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <TaskHeader @add-tasks="handleAddTasks" />
        <div>
            <TaskBody   :tasks=tasks
                        @add-dragged-task='handleAddDropTask'
                        @toggle-side-panel='handleTogglePanel'
                        @delete-task='handleDeleteTask' />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import TaskHeader from './TaskHeader.vue';
    import TaskBody from './TaskBody.vue';
    import { reactive, ref } from '@vue/reactivity';
    
    export default {
        name: 'TaskContainer',

        components: {
            TaskHeader,
            TaskBody
        },

        setup(props, context) {
            const monthTasks = reactive({});
            const tasks = ref([]);

            function handleRemoveDropTask(droppedTaskName) {
                console.group('TaskBody_handleRemoveDropTask');
                console.log('droppedTaskName ', droppedTaskName);
                const dropTask = props.allTasks.find(t => t.tName == droppedTaskName);
                console.log('dropTask ', dropTask);

                monthTasks[dropTask.tStartMonth] = monthTasks[dropTask.tStartMonth]
                                                                      .filter(t => t.tName != droppedTaskName);
                console.log('monthTasks ', monthTasks);

                console.log('BEFORE: tasks ', tasks.value, 'lenght ', tasks.value.length);
                tasks.value = tasks.value.filter(t => t.tName != droppedTaskName);
                console.log('BEFORE: tasks ', tasks.value, 'lenght ', tasks.value.length);

                console.group('TaskBody_handleRemoveDropTask');
            }

            function handleAddTasks(singleTask) {
                console.group('TaskContainer_handleAddTasks');
                tasks.value.push(singleTask);
                monthTasks[props.activeMonth] = tasks.value;
                console.log('adding to month\'s tasks ', monthTasks);
                context.emit('add-to-all-tasks', singleTask);
                console.groupEnd('TaskContainer_handleAddTasks');
            }
            
            function handleDeleteTask(taskName) {
                console.group('TaskContainer_handleDeleteTask');
                console.log('taskName ', taskName);
                console.log('monthTasks ', monthTasks[props.activeMonth].filter(t => t.tName != taskName));
                monthTasks[props.activeMonth] = monthTasks[props.activeMonth].filter(t => t.tName != taskName);
                console.log('monthTasks ', monthTasks);
                console.log('BEFORE: tasks ', tasks.value, 'lenght ', tasks.value.length);
                tasks.value = tasks.value.filter(t => t.tName != taskName);
                console.log('BEFORE: tasks ', tasks.value, 'lenght ', tasks.value.length);
                context.emit('close-side-panel', taskName);
                context.emit('del-from-all-tasks', taskName);
                console.groupEnd('TaskContainer_handleDeleteTask');
            }

            function handleAddDropTask(dropTaskName) {
                console.group('TaskContainer_handleAddDropTask');
                const dropTask = props.allTasks.find(t => t.tName == dropTaskName);

                dropTask.tStartMonth = props.activeMonth;
                console.log('dropTask ', dropTask);
                console.log('props.allTasks ', props.allTasks);

                console.log('monthTasks ', monthTasks);
                console.log('monthTasks ', monthTasks[props.activeMonth]);
                if(monthTasks[props.activeMonth] == undefined) {
                    tasks.value = []
                    monthTasks[props.activeMonth] = tasks.value;
                }
                console.log('monthTasks ', monthTasks[props.activeMonth].filter(t => t.tName != dropTaskName));
                monthTasks[props.activeMonth] = monthTasks[props.activeMonth].filter(t => t.Name != dropTaskName);
                monthTasks[props.activeMonth].push(dropTask);
                console.log('monthTasks ', monthTasks);

                console.log('BEFORE: tasks ', tasks, 'length ', tasks.value.length);
                tasks.value = tasks.value.filter(t => t.Name != dropTaskName);
                tasks.value.push(dropTask);
                console.log('AFTER: tasks ', tasks, 'length ', tasks.value.length);
                console.groupEnd('TaskContainer_handleAddDropTask');
            }

            function handleTogglePanel(tsk) {
                console.group('TaskContainer_handleTogglePanel');
                context.emit('toggle-side-panel', tsk);
                console.groupEnd('TaskContainer_handleTogglePanel');
            }

            return {
                tasks,
                handleAddTasks,
                handleTogglePanel,
                handleDeleteTask,
                handleAddDropTask,
                handleRemoveDropTask
            }
        },

        props: ['allTasks', 'activeMonth'],
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

One of the features is the ability to drag a task from one month to another month. As can be seen from the picture I am able to drag and drop from `Jan` month to `Feb` month, there by creating the task in the `Feb` month, but in order to remove the task from the `Jan` month, I need access to the `Jan` month's `TaskContainer`'s reactive `tasks` or `monthTasks` variable in `Feb` month as each `TaskContainer` is an instance created inside the `v-for` of the `CalendarBody`'s template.

[image: output]

My questions are:

1. How can I access `Jan` months instance (specifically `tasks` or `monthTasks` variables) inside `Feb` month, so that I can remove the task `1` from the variables, so that the task doesn't remain in `Jan`.
2. Is this the correct way to create `TaskContainer` component? That is, declaring `TaskContainer` inside the `v-for` thereby creating a instance for each month or should I have hard coded `TaskContainer` 12 times?
3. I read that a prop passed down from the parent should not be modified in child but rather only in the parent. I am finding this bit hard to implement as it is much easier to simply change a value where I want instead of emitting event to the parent for every small change. As mine is bit nested I have to emit from child to grandparent or even great grandparent. Any suggestions on how to emit directly to the component I need, something similar to provide/inject for props but for emitting?

PS:

1. I am using just the base VUE without any other framework/library.
2. Please ignore the CSS also as it is only a makeshift.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use vuex (vue store) for your app. So you can track all the information app-wide. Plan B should be use your parent component.

   this.$parent

will give you parent component but be aware if you wrap this child component you should call 1 more $parent.

2. V-for should be correct way to follow.
3. You can't modify props in the child Vue will throw an error. As I said you can create vuex store or you can cal as many as you like $parent and handle all items in the parent

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example where using a store makes your life easier. Official Vue recommendation is https://pinia.vuejs.org/

To answer your questions specifically:

1. You should keep all this state in a store and then you can easily access it from any component without worrying how to access some component specifically
2. It is completely OK to use `v-for` to create multiple instances of a component.
3. When using a store you will have avoided issues with passing props through multiple layers of components aka "prop drilling". Modifying data in a Pinia store is as simple as modifying it directly or by using `$patch` https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#mutating-the-state